# Macro with inline asm in c is having formatting problems

Tags: c, assembly, macros

I'm trying to write a macro in c that embeds a string within itself and returns a pointer to the string when run.

```
#include <unistd.h>

#define STR(str)
{(char* var = 0;
    asm volatile(               \
        "call after_string%=\n" \
        ".ascii " str "\n"      \
        ".byte 0\n"             \
        "after_string%=:\n"     \
        "pop $0\n"              \
        : "=m" (var) );
    var;
)}


int main() {
    write(0, STR("hello"), 7);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the errors:

```
inline.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 {(char* var = 0;
 ^
inline.c: In function ‘main’:
inline.c:17:23: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
  write(0, STR("hello"), 6);
```

I can't figure out how to fix this; any help is welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but that looks like doomed by design.

Comment: @Olaf Can you specify why? It seems like it should work to me.

Comment: Don't have an answer at the moment, but to debug macros you should look at the compiler intermediate files.  For gcc this is the '--save-temps' option.  Here is the relevant intermediate file for your code:

`# 2 "test.c" 2


{(char* var = 0;
    asm volatile( "call after_string%=\n" ".ascii " str "\n" ".byte 0\n" "after_string%=:\n" "pop $0\n" : "=m" (var) );






    var;
)}


int main() {
    write(0, , 7);
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: "It seems like it should work to me" - The compiler and I seem to disagree.

Comment: @Olaf Well, I think that the concept of it should work. It obviously doesn't work in practice currently.

Comment: The macro yields nothing for a start. But as I suspect you just forgot two backslashes, my comment stands even if you add them.

Comment: @DavidBryson Isn't that the code just compacted onto one line. Well, I suppose that it shows that STR() doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: You're missing \ line continuation characters at the end of the first two lines and the penultimate two lines!

Comment: @Olaf It works now: https://ghostbin.com/paste/j7auu

Ignore the warning that gcc omits when compiling.

Comment: @Fluffy: "It works does not imply it does **not** invoke undefined behaviour. It actually is the worst form of UB, because you neven can be sure it will not cause problems under certain conditions. So, in C warnings should be treated serious. If you get a warning for `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`, you definitively should respect it. As a personal note: Everyone showing such code in a professional project will have a very hard time. (as would a student of mine have for a university project). Before getting fancy with macros and assembler, put some thought if that is really the right way.

Comment: @Olaf The only warning that gcc throws for me is that printf doesn't have a format string. That can easily be fixed by adding a format string.

Comment: @Fluffy: Did you even understand the first part of my comment? (Rhetorical question; I'll leave this discussion; We continue if I see such code from a co-worker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which compiler are you using?

GCC (and probably Clang as a GCC compatibility feature) has an extension, [Statements and declarations in expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), which uses the notation:

```
({ … })
```

You appear to be trying to use the following, which has the characters in the reverse order:

```
{( … )}
```

Neither of these notations is standard C.

---

Also, as shown in the question, the code:

```
#define STR(str)
{(char* var = 0;
    asm volatile(               \
        "call after_string%=\n" \
        ".ascii " str "\n"      \
        ".byte 0\n"             \
        "after_string%=:\n"     \
        "pop $0\n"              \
        : "=m" (var) );
    var;
)}
```

appears to be missing a number of backslashes:

```
#define STR(str)                \
{(char* var = 0;                \
    asm volatile(               \
        "call after_string%=\n" \
        ".ascii " str "\n"      \
        ".byte 0\n"             \
        "after_string%=:\n"     \
        "pop $0\n"              \
        : "=m" (var) );         \
    var;                        \
)}
```

That makes the block into a single macro.  As written, it's a macro with an empty expansion, followed by a statement block where the first contained statement starts with a left parenthesis.  If you want it to be a statement expression, you need to use:

```
#define STR(str)                    \
    ({char* var = 0;                \
        asm volatile(               \
            "call after_string%=\n" \
            ".ascii " str "\n"      \
            ".byte 0\n"             \
            "after_string%=:\n"     \
            "pop $0\n"              \
            : "=m" (var) );         \
        var;                        \
    })
```

I reserve judgement on whether the result is valid — I've never found it necessary to embed assembler in code because I work on portable software.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the formatting issues. The assembly doesn't quite work, but thanks anyway.